# Calculating $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb C^*, \mathbb C^*)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to calculate this group.

So far I noticed that if $h:\mathbb C^* \to \mathbb C^*$ is a homomorphism, then $h(z)=h(1\cdot z)=h(1)\cdot h(z)$ for any $z\in \mathbb C^*$. Thus $h(1)=1$.
Further I know that for any $t\in \mathbb C$ $h_t: z\mapsto z^t$ satisfies $h(xy)=(xy)^t=x^ty^t=h(x)h(y)$. So this is an homomorphism, hence  $\operatorname{Hom} (\mathbb C^*, \mathbb C^*)\subset \mathbb C.$

But is this an equality, or are there more homomorphisms?

Comment: $z^t$ is not well defined if $t \notin \Bbb Z$.

Comment: If $t\notin\Bbb Z$, then $z\mapsto z^t$ (whatever that is) is not a homomorphism. If you believe AC then there are lots of homomorphisms.

Comment: Complex conjugation is one additional homomorphism you can write down (and of of course all composition of it with the homomorphisms you already mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

One can classify simply the **continuous** homomorphisms from $\Bbb C^*$
to itself. They are the maps
$$z\mapsto z^n\exp(a\ln|z|)$$
where $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $a\in\Bbb C$.

But assuming the axiom of choice, one proves that $\Bbb C^*$
is isomorphic to the additive $(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)\times\bigoplus_I\Bbb Q$
where $I$ is an uncountable index set. This group has $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$
automorphisms, an awful lot.

Comment: I see that the defined map is a continuous homomorphism. But how can we be sure that there are no others?

Answer (score 2):

Multiplicative notation is not common in abelian group theory.

We can use the fact that $\mathbb{C}^*\cong\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{T}$, where $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, via
$$
(r,u+\mathbb{Z})\mapsto e^r(\cos(2\pi u)+i\sin(2\pi u))
$$
Thus the group of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^*$ is the direct sum of
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\Hom(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\oplus\Hom(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{T})\oplus
\Hom(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{T})\oplus\Hom(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{R})
$$

The first two groups are big $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, the third one is a wild beast. If we consider the exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{T}\to0$, then we have
$$
0\to\Hom(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{T})\to\Hom(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{T})\to\Hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{T})\to0
$$
and $\Hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{T})\cong\mathbb{T}$. So $\Hom(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{T})$ sits in a big $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space so that the cokernel is $\mathbb{T}$.

What's $\Hom(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{R})$? A similar sequence arises:
$$
0\to\Hom(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{R})\to\Hom(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\to\Hom(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R})\to0
$$

As you see, the group $\Hom(\mathbb{C}^*,\mathbb{C}^*)$ is *much* bigger than $\mathbb{C}$.